# Xamarin forms build success but deploy failed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I receive this warning when ever I try to deploy my Xamarin.Froms app to any device or emulator. Also the deploy fails without any errors. I cannot run my app. Can Any one please help me?

> The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll (vv8.0)
>   is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.1).
>   You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your
>   project.  App2.Android    C:\Users\subas\source\repos\App2\App2\App2.Android\App2.Android.csproj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT/UPDATE**

Right now JDK9 and the Android SDK tools are not compatible with each other - thus Xamarin.Android does not work with JDK9.

Run the following to see the version of java you have installed:

```
java -version
```

If it reports something along the lines of **java version "9.0.4"** you have JDK9.

Specifically there's an issue with the apksigner. It's not using the `-classpath` switch that the JDK expects.

Easiest way to fix is to install the JDK8 and make sure your `PATH` is pointed at it.

This [documentation](https://msou.co/bge) gives a solid overview.

**ORIGINAL**

Sounds like the target Android framework in the project needs to be updated to point to the latest version of Android.

First - make sure you have the latest Android SDKs installed. Here's some [documentation](https://msou.co/bfu) on that.

Once you have the latest - here is how to make sure you're targeting the latest - depending on the IDE you're using:

**Visual Studio Mac**

1. In the solution explorer, right click the Android project and select options.
2. Under the **Build** -> **General** node - select *"Use latest installed platform"* from the **Target Framework** dropdown.
3. Save everything, close the solution, restart VS-Mac

**Visual Studio**

1. Right click the Android project in the solution explorer and select properties
2. Under the **Application** node, select *Use Latest Platform* from the **Compile Using Android Version** dropdown.
3. Save everything, close the solution, restart Visual Studio

Comment: Hi @Matt,
Your answer got rid of the warning but I cannot still deploy the application. I get following message in the build output. 

`Unexpected install output: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl596958863.tmp/base.apk: Attempt to get length of null array]`

Comment: @Subash try cleaning your solution (then double checking that the /bin & /obj folders are empty - if not delete everything) - then try running again, making sure you have the Debug configuration selected.

Comment: I did and that did not help either.

Comment: What version of the JDK do you have installed?

Comment: Also check to see there's a file in the /bin/Debug directory named {project-name}-Signed.apk .... if so - from the android command prompt run: "adb -d install {path-to-apk}"

Comment: I have jdk 9 installed and i tried running "adb -d install " but I get the message `error: no devices found
adb: error: failed to get feature set: no devices found
- waiting for device -` 
But when I do "adb devices" I see my emulator in the list.

Comment: As per @MattSoucoup original answer JDK 9 is not compatible. That said, I am using JDK 8 and have that same certificate error. I have tried many things (including cleaning and deleting those folders) and have no luck. Even with a blank new project. Although I have seen several people saying removing JDK 9 resolved their issue so it is worth a shot for you I guess.